# How to get the package versions corresponding to Unity 7 launcher applications?

Tags: unity, command-line, python, python3

I'd like to know the Ubuntu package version of all applications locked into my
Unity (7) Launcher from the command line.

[image]

The command should return a list of packages names and their versions, filtering
applications manually installed (like MakeMKV in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query Unity using its [python API](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/python/Unity-7.0.html), the following command will find all the corresponding [desktop files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) and will query `dpkg` to know the package providing them:

```
python3 -c 'from gi.repository import Unity; a = Unity.AppInfoManager.get_instance(); \
[print(a.get_path(app)) for app in  Unity.LauncherFavorites.get_default().enumerate_ids()]' | \
xargs dpkg -S 2>&1 | \
grep -v "no path found matching pattern" | \
awk -F: '{print $1}' | \
xargs dpkg-query -W
```

On my system it returns:

```
bzr-explorer    1.3.0-2
firefox 30.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.3
geany   1.23.1+dfsg-1
gnome-terminal  3.6.2-0ubuntu1
nautilus    1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.1
pidgin  1:2.10.9-0ubuntu3.1
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu 3.0.1+14.04.20140415-0ubuntu1
synaptic    0.81.1ubuntu1
thunderbird 1:24.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
unity-webapps-googlecalendar    2.4.16+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: You could also parse the output of `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites`.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Excellent idea, I often forget to look at what dconf/gsettings can provide. Thanks